# Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\Two\User::createToken()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-socialite

In a laravel 5.8 API project, I want users to login via their social accounts. So far I have been able to use Socialite to retrieve user info from the provider and use it to create a new user record. But when I try to have the user log in again, it throws up the following error

> Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\Two\User::createToken()

Here's the code I am working with

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Socialite;
use App\SocialAccount;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;

class SocialAuthController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $socialUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

        $userSocialAccount = SocialAccount::where('provider_id', $socialUser->id)->where('provider_name', $provider)->first();

        /*
         if account exist, return the social account user
         else create the user account, then return the new user
        */
        if ($userSocialAccount) {

            // generate access token for use
            $token = $socialUser->createToken('********')->accessToken;

            // return access token & user data
            return response()->json([
                'token' => $token,
                'user'  => (new UserResource($userSocialAccount))
            ]);

        } else {

            $user = User::create([
                'firstname'            => $socialUser->name,
                'lastname'             => $socialUser->name,
                'username'             => $socialUser->email,
                'email_verified_at'    => now()
            ]);

            if ($user) {

                SocialAccount::create([
                    'provider_id'   => $socialUser->id,
                    'provider_name' => $provider,
                    'user_id'       => $user->id
                ]);
            }

            // assign passport token to user
            $token = $user->createToken('********')->accessToken;

            return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'user' => new UserResource($user)]);

        }
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to spot the reason why I am getting the error when the user attempts a second login but there is no error if it's the first time the user logs in with a social account.

Why does it complain about `Laravel\Socialite\Two\User::createToken()` method? If I try adding this line `use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User` vscode intelephsense flags it as a duplicate of `App\User` so what is really going on in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the problem I was having with having a token generated by passport for users authentication after the first social login was because I was calling the `createToken` method on the user returned by `Socialite`. As explained by @JorisJ1 `Socialite` does not have the `createToken` function so my initial code threw an error.

Here's how I fixed it

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    // retrieve social user info
    $socialUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    // check if social user provider record is stored
    $userSocialAccount = SocialAccount::where('provider_id', $socialUser->id)->where('provider_name', $provider)->first();

    if ($userSocialAccount) {

        // retrieve the user from users store
        $user = User::find($userSocialAccount->user_id);

        // assign access token to user
        $token = $user->createToken('Pramopro')->accessToken;

        // return access token & user data
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'user'  => (new UserResource($user))
        ]);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comments are welcomed if there is a better way for adding social authentication to API.

Answer (score 1):

I think your last sentence hits the problem: the `Laravel\Socialite\Two\User` and `App\User` are two fully separate entities.

The `Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user()` provides you with a `Socialite` User whereas `User::create` creates an `App\User`.

The second `$token = $user->createToken('********')->accessToken;` works because `App\User` has the `createToken` function and the other does not.

Comment: Your explanation forced me to think and I was able to come up with a solution.